# Capacitor choice

Tags: led, capacitor, circuit-design

I'm building an electronic circuit for switching between car daytime lights and turn signals, but I can't figure out which capacitor to use.

The components that I will use:

- 3W high-power LEDs
- Suitable constant current LED drivers
- SRA-12VDC-CL relay
- Diodes
- Capacitor

The attached circuit is a replica of a circuit I found and it's working well, I just can't figure out the suitable capacitor.

[image]

Comment: To the op --> What 10 uF capacitors have you considered? What's the maximum overload voltage that can be seen in automotive applications? What are "car daytime lights"?

Comment: Before you do anything, is the modified car intended to be used in public streets, and if yes, is the operating of the lights street legal according to your local laws? Are the components automotive-rated, as the last thing you want is a broken relay or random operation of lights during shock and vibration. There is a reason why legislation says how lights should operate, and weirdly acting lights draw attention and that attention drawn to your blinky lights leaves less attention to safety of others.

Comment: Welcome! Your schematic is hard wo follow. Please follow best practices and draw positive voltages pointing up, ground and negative ones pointing down. Input signals come from the left and output signals exit to the right. Signal flow is left to right. Draw LEDs as LEDs.